# R devtools and packages dependencies in DESCRIPTION Remotes

Tags: r, devtools, remotes

I would like to use a dev version of a package in my own package.
As detailed in [devtools vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html), I included the following line of code in the DESCRIPTION file of my package:

`Remotes: SciViews/svDialogs`

tried also:

`Remotes: SciViews/svDialogs@v1.0.2`

Unfortunately, that dependency is not installed  prior to the installation of my package. Running, `devtools::install_deps()` does not install that dependency, but installs any missing dependency in `Imports`.

On the other hand `devtools::install_github("SciViews/svDialogs")` works as expected and installs the dev version of the package.

Not sure if I am missing something important. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else runs in the some problem...
Solution was provided by @jennybc on the [package page](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2142).

The dependency need to be listed in the `Imports` section of the `DESCRIPTION` too. This is actually stated in the vignette but I somewhat missed.